# What is the default response payload to send from Node.js for Dialogflow

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es

```
   const payload = {
            payload: {
                google: {
                    expectUserResponse: true,
                    richResponse: {
                        items: [
                            {
                                simpleResponse: {
                                    ssml: 'hi i am vamsi',
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                },
            },
        };
```

I'm using above payload for sending a response to google assistant.

I want to know payload to send as the default response because this response only displays on google assistant. I need a default to display for every platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [webhook response](https://github.com/dialogflow/fulfillment-webhook-json/blob/master/responses/v2/response.json) can be as simple as

```
{
  "fulfillmentText": "Hi I am Vamsi"
}
```

Comment: in programming, everything seems to be as simple when we know